# Como passar o excedente de dias do Period para meses

Tags: java, data

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula o intervalo entre duas datas e soma o resultado à um period com .plus, depois faz o mesmo processo com outro intervalo e assim por diante. O problema é que não passa o excedente de dias para meses, por exemplo se eu somar 4 vezes da data 02/08/2007 até 20/11/2022 vai dar 61 anos e 72 dias, ou seja passa 12 meses para 1 ano mas não passa 28,29,30 ou 31 dias para 1 mês.

```
    formatoLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    localDataInicial = LocalDate.parse(DataInicial.getText(), formatoLocalDate);
    localDataFinal = LocalDate.parse(DataFinal.getText(), formatoLocalDate);

    periodoDeTrabalho = Period.between(localDataInicial, localDataFinal);
    
    // Problema: "tempoDeTrabalho" não passa o excedente de dias para meses //

    tempoDeTrabalho = tempoDeTrabalho.plus(periodoDeTrabalho);
    tempoDeTrabalho = tempoDeTrabalho.normalized();
```

Comment: Como já explicado abaixo, não dá pra converter a quantidade de dias em meses e dias da maneira que vc quer, pois isso depende das datas envolvidas. Ex: 32 dias é 1 mês e quantos dias? Pode ser 1, 2, 3 ou 4. E como esses períodos são calculados usando intervalos diferentes (portanto, datas diferentes envolvidas), tal conversão se torna inviável.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Com a resposta de cima meu código ficou assim:

```
    formatoLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    localDataInicial = LocalDate.parse(DataInicial.getText(), formatoLocalDate);
    localDataFinal = LocalDate.parse(DataFinal.getText(), formatoLocalDate);
    
    localDataFinalComPeriodo = localDataFinal.plus(tempoDeTrabalho);

    periodoDeTrabalho = Period.between(localDataInicial, localDataFinal);
    tempoDeTrabalho = Period.between(localDataInicial, localDataFinalComPeriodo);
    tempoDeTrabalho = tempoDeTrabalho.normalized();
```

Basicamente o "periodDeTrabalho" é apenas para ir mostrando a diferença entre cada periodo.

Answer (score -2):

De acordo com a documentação, não normalizar os dias é o comportamento esperado, veja: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#normalized()

Eu encontrei a resposta abaixo com uma explicação que faz sentido.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021504/3334365

Basicamente ela diz que 1 ano sempre tem 12 meses e 12 meses sempre será 1 ano. Assim a normalização é possível.

Contudo, a duração dos meses é variável, logo não seria possível normalizar os dias já que não dá para saber qual a duração dos meses deveria ser considerada.

Afinal, um `Period` pode representar qualquer período de qualquer ano. Este período poderia ou não incluir fevereiro, que tem menos dias e, poderia ou não incluir um ano bissexto.

No seu caso, acredito que a forma correta de resolver o problema é somar o tal período à data final e só depois disto, calcular a diferença entre ela e a data inicial. Veja um exemplo:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

public class App {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Period periodo = Period.of(2, 8, 300);

    LocalDate dataInicial = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1);

    LocalDate dataFinal = LocalDate.of(2022, 7, 1);

    LocalDate dataFinalComPeriodo = dataFinal.plus(periodo);

    Period periodoTotal = Period.between(dataInicial, dataFinalComPeriodo);

    System.out.println(periodoTotal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, faz dias que eu estava tentando resolver isso. O jeito que você mostrou é bem mais fácil do que a gambiarra que eu estava cogitando fazer.